# How To Get Pinescript To Count?

Tags: pine-script, stock, pine-script-v4, pine-script-v5

I'm currently trying to make a script that will essentially count the amount of bullish signals in your chart, then plot the number of bullish signs above each candlestick that has them.

I already have my patterns, variables, and signals, defined.

Just need help making the plot. I can't figure out how to make it correctly count the signals,
then display that number over the candlesticks.

Thank you for answers!!!

(prefer V4 but any answers would be great!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//@version=4
study("", overlay = true, max_labels_count = 500)

bull_cond1 = crossover(ema(close,13), ema(close,20))
bull_cond2 = close > open
bull_cond3 = close > close[2]


bool global_bull_cond = bull_cond1 or bull_cond2 or bull_cond3 

int bull_count = 0


if global_bull_cond
    if bull_cond1
        bull_count += 1
    if bull_cond2
        bull_count += 1
    if bull_cond3
        bull_count += 1
    label.new(x = bar_index, y = high, style = label.style_label_down, size = size.tiny, color = color.lime, textcolor = color.black, text = tostring(bull_count))
```